# Performance of Java local vs global variable in main game loop

Tags: java, performance, global-variables, local-variables

I have a main loop on my Java game server.  I am wondering if converting local variables to global variables will help performance.  Running this sample scenario (ii < 100) shows the opposite.

- averageMethodRunTimeHashtable: {localVariableMethod=628,
  globalVariableMethod=888}
- averageMethodRunTimeHashtable:
  {localVariableMethod=601, globalVariableMethod=899}
- averageMethodRunTimeHashtable: {localVariableMethod=543,
  globalVariableMethod=773}
- averageMethodRunTimeHashtable:
  {localVariableMethod=513, globalVariableMethod=800}

Running (ii < 1000000) or for longer shows inconsistent results.  Any suggestions/insight here?

```
import java.util.Hashtable;

class HelloWorld {
    static Hashtable<String, Long> averageMethodRunTimeHashtable = new Hashtable<>();
    static long topTime = 0l;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //boolean stopServer = false; //usually stopped by an external source
        //while (!stopServer){ //normally this runs "forever"
        for (int ii = 0; ii < 100; ii++){ //for this example just run 100 times
            topTime = System.nanoTime();
            localVariableMethod();
            averageMethodRunTime("localVariableMethod", (System.nanoTime() - topTime));
        
            topTime = System.nanoTime();
            globalVariableMethod();
            averageMethodRunTime("globalVariableMethod", (System.nanoTime() - topTime));
        }
        
        System.out.println("averageMethodRunTimeHashtable: " + averageMethodRunTimeHashtable);
    }
    
    public static void localVariableMethod(){
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++){
            int test = i;
        }
    }
    
    static int test_globalVariableMethod = 0;
    public static void globalVariableMethod(){
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++){
            test_globalVariableMethod = i;
        }
    }
    
    public static void averageMethodRunTime(String method, long time) {
        if (averageMethodRunTimeHashtable.containsKey(method)) {
            averageMethodRunTimeHashtable.put(method, (time + averageMethodRunTimeHashtable.get(method)) / 2);
        } else {
            averageMethodRunTimeHashtable.put(method, time);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You're not going to notice a difference. The reason for inconsistent results is most likely because the runtime notices that `test` variable in never read after assignment, and optimizing away the assignment.

Answer (score -1):

I am trying to answer this part of your question:

> I am wondering if converting local variables to global variables will help performance.

There is always some subjectivity in matters of performance based on the context, machine, the way we write the code, etc. And also how we measure it! The measurement itself may add its own overhead.

Jotting down what I feel are by and large true regarding the matter. And based on the below, more often than not, going for local variables more likely to help performance more than long-lived ones (global).

- **Object creation is fairly cheap in Java**. Hence, we don't need to worry about the cost at the time of creation
- **GC isn't cheap**. More objects you have to collect, the more time it may need to do GC.

  - Long-lived objects score here.
- **Long-lived variables have** the following **concerns**, which are addressed in local variables. (However, sometimes you do need global variables. If you have addressed these, then great.)

  1. Any code with access can edit     *(doesn't contribute directly to the performance issue)*
  2. Can lead to memory leaks, eg, `Map`s     *(this contributes to the performance issue)*

### When to go for long-lived variables

1. When the variable will **not** have "deeply" linked objects, like collections or even normal Java object which refer to other objects, which further refer to others, etc.
2. When the value of the variable is constant, even if it is a collection. That is, static collections.
3. When the programmer is sure he/she needs it due to the needs of the program.